# Strange behavior of org-agenda-files initialization

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I am using emacs-27.1 build 1 and org-mode 9.3.7 under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

### Situation 1:

If I restart emacs and call org-agenda the 'Agenda for current week or day' shows only days of the week.  I ran emacs-25.1 prior to 27.1 and the behavior then was to load the agenda files and show the agenda, with the time-stamped journal entries, calendar entries, TODOs, etc.

The value of `org-agenda-files` is nil after start-up. Org-mode otherwise seems to be normal.

The following is the start of my org-configuration:

```el
(use-package org
  :ensure t)

(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("~/org/todo.org"
                                 "~/org/journal.org"
                                 "~/org/calendar.org")))
```

Loading `init.el` and evaluating the buffer does not set `org-agenda-files`

Evaluating the s-expression itself (put cursor after the s-expression containing `setq` and `C-x C-e`) sets `org-agenda-files` and restores the normal behavior - calling org-agenda loads the agenda files and shows the proper agenda. I have tried putting the variable initiation inside the `use-package` (following `:init`)with the same result - the variable is not set on start-up, but is after evaluating the s-expression.

### Situation 2

I use two themes a day: a light theme for daytime and a dark one for night.

After `M-x disable-theme` and `M-x enable-theme` `org-agenda-files` is set to `nil` and the above behavior pertains!  I have to eval the expression that sets org-agenda.  The reset happens after `enable-theme`.  It does not appear to matter what theme is enabled (I have tried three).

The manual adjustment for each case only requires a few seconds, but it is annoying and interrupts the work flow.  How can I avoid having to manually set org-agenda-files?

Comment: One question per question please: I suggest you move your "Problem 2" into a separate question.

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm getting the same problem two different ways.  Perhaps I should have sub-titled 'Situation I' and 'Situation II'

Comment: For problem 1, try putting the `setq` form inside the `use-package` form after `:config`.  This will set `org-agenda-files` after `org` has loaded and this might help.

Comment: What's the question? Try formulating it as "How can I...".

Comment: @FranBurstall:  This did not work either.